# useMemo hook always True even the location.pathname change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-usememo

I am trying to render a specific Layout if the location change and I'm using the useMemo hook to validate the route and render the based on this value but it always returns true even the route change for example the new route is .../SSDSD/draft

```
const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location)
  const showShadow = useMemo(() => ['preview', 'signing', 'receipts'].some(word => location.pathname.includes(word)), [location]);
  const isHomePage = useMemo(() => ['/', '/search', '/addressbook'].some(word => location.pathname.includes(word)), [location]);
  console.log(isHomePage);
  //debugger;
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Box className={isHomePage ? classes.homeBackground : classes.innerBackground}>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: try using `location.pathname` as the dependency

Comment: Still the same 
```
const isHomePage = useMemo(() => ['/', '/search', '/addressbook'].some(word => location.pathname.includes(word)), [location.pathname]);
```
The console
```
  console.log(location)
```
Object
hash: ""
key: "vvj7z7"
pathname: "/EP1001E2K/draft"
search: ""
state: null
[[Prototype]]: Object
```
console.log(isHomePage);
```
Layout.js:66 true

Comment: log the pathname inside useMemo's callback and check if it's being updated

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you include `"/"` in the array. [`location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname) always begins with a `"/"`, so this will always be true.

```js
const result = ['/', 'any string', 'any other string', 'doesnt matter'].some(str => location.pathname.includes(str));
console.log(result); // always true
```

Instead, you probably want to include all pathnames which actually represent your "homepage" and use [`str.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead of [`str.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), using something like this:

```js
const isHomePage = useMemo(() => (
  location.pathname === '/'
  || ['/search', '/addressbook'].some(str => location.pathname.startsWith(str))
), [location]);
```